# Reselect active cell in Access subform following requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform displaying a data set containing up to 200 rows and up to 35 columns. When a user selects a cell a part of the UI is enabled allowing them to add/edit records, following which the subform needs to refresh so the user can see the effect of their changes, which is triggered by the `AfterUpdate` event.

The issue I have is that when the subform is refreshed, by calling `Requery`, the focus is shifted to the top left of the subform, meaning that not only can the user not see the effect of their change, but they have also lost their place.

I have managed to get the subform to reselect the current record by capturing and setting the `Form.Recordset.AbsolutePosition` property, but can't find any way to set the focus to the column that the user was in previously.

The code I have currently is:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

    Dim lngCurrentPos As Long

    With Form_frmMain.subfrm_Results_Review
        lngCurrentPos = .Form.Recordset.AbsolutePosition
        .Requery
        .Form.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = lngCurrentPos
    End With

End Sub
```

But is there anyway to set focus back to a specific cell? It seems there should be a way as this must be a common problem?

Comment: you can use the bookmark to get the current position and do the refresh and set the bookmark again.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how this works? I've tried storing the `.Form.Bookmark` in a variant before calling `Requery`, but I get a 'Not a valid bookmark' error when I try to set it again

Comment: I assuming you do mean "Form" wherever you wrote "Report" in your question, as reports in Access are not editable at all. - Please edit the question, that it will be properly indexed for searching.

Comment: Yes, you were correct, and I have now edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the focus to the previously selected control of a form by extending your VBA code as follows.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

    Dim lngCurrentPos As Long
    Dim strControlName as String

    With Form_frmMain.subfrm_Results_Review
        strControlName = .Form.ActiveControl.Name
        lngCurrentPos = .Form.Recordset.AbsolutePosition
        .Requery
        .Form.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = lngCurrentPos
        .Form.Controls(strControlName).SetFocus
    End With

End Sub
```